# Distinguishing between elements of a given list

Tags: list-manipulation

In a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128850/distinguishing-between-the-solutions-of-a-system-of-equations) I asked how to distinguish between the roots of a system of equations. However I did not obtain any working solution, so let's make things simpler now.

Assuming we have the following list

```
data = {{-0.613042, 3.72089*10^-20}, {0.3, 0.0631203}, 
        {0.3, -0.0631203}, {0.302369, 8.6956*10^-17}, 
        {0.969193, 4.35961*10^-19}}
```

As we can see, it contains five elements corresponding to five points on the $(x,y)$ plane. Three of them lie on the $x$ axis, while the other two have non zero value of $y$.

I want to create a second list, `data2`, containing the following information

```
data2 = {xL1, xL2, xL3, xL4, yL4}
```

where

- xL2 is the root on the $x$ axis with the highest value of $x$,
- xL3 is the root on the $x$ axis with the smallest value of $x$,
- xL1 is the root on the $x$ axis which is between xL2 and xL3,
- xL4 is the root on the (x,y) plane with non zero value of $y$,
- yL4 is the corresponding value of xL4.

For this example we have `xL1 = 0.302369`, `xL2 = 0.969193`, `xL3 = -0.613042`, and `(xL4, yL4) = (0.3, 0.0631203)`.

**Note 1:** The determination of the elements of `data2` should be done automatically for every given list (`data`).

**Note 2:** In some cases the initial list could contain only three elements which are the three points on the $x$ axis. For example we could have

```
data = {{-2.00803, 2.31869*10^-23}, {0.738218, -1.29609*10^-15}, 
        {1.75066, -1.61207*10^-18}}
```

In this case, `data2` should contain only `data2 = {xL1, xL2, xL3}` without printing `Null` in the 4th and 5th position.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are `xL1` etc just the x-value of the root, or the x-y tuple?

Comment: @Quantum_Oli It's just the x-value. For this example we have `xL1 = 0.302369`, `xL2 = 0.969193`, `xL3 = -0.613042`, and `(xL4, yL4) = (0.3, 0.0631203)`.

Comment: I think your definition does not specify that `yL4` should be positive.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Both roots with non-zero values of $y$ have the same absolute value of $y$, so it does not really matter whether you take the positive or the negative one. We could always take the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `SortBy` with two sorting criteria to first produce those roots on the x-axis, then the final two (if present):

```
SecondList[data_] := Module[{data2},
  data2 = SortBy[Chop@data, {Abs[Last[#]] &, First}];
  Join[data2[[{2, 3, 1}, 1]], If[Length[data2] > 3, {data[[4,1]], Abs[data2[[4,2]]]}, {}]]
]

data = {{-0.613042, 3.72089*10^-20}, {0.3, 0.0631203}, 
    {0.3, -0.0631203}, {0.302369, 8.6956*10^-17}, 
    {0.969193, 4.35961*10^-19}}

SecondList[data]
```

> {0.302369, 0.969193, -0.613042, 0.3, 0.0631203}

```
data = {{-2.00803, 2.31869*10^-23}, {0.738218, -1.29609*10^-15}, 
    {1.75066, -1.61207*10^-18}}

SecondList[data]
```

> {0.738218, 1.75066, -2.00803}

Comment: It works, however according to the current definition in the module it prints (xL1, xL3, xL2, xL4, yL4). It should be `SecondList[data_] := Module[{data2},
  data2 = SortBy[Chop@data, {Abs[Last[#]] &, First}];
  Join[data2[[{2, 3, 1}, 1]], If[Length[data2] > 3, Abs[data2[[4]]], {}]]
]`

Comment: Well spotted, easily fixed.

Comment: I noticed that in the case of 5 roots the `Abs` applies on both the x and y coordinates. This is bad. It should apply only on the y coordinate.

Comment: Again, easily fixed. Sloppy this morning..!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to say `xL4` and `yL4` as whole `data` is on xy plane. For the others

```
data = {{-0.613042, 3.72089*10^-20}, {0.3, 0.0631203}, {0.3, -0.0631203}, 
        {0.302369, 8.6956*10^-17}, {0.969193, 4.35961*10^-19}};

xL2[list__] := Sort[Select[list, Abs[#[[2]]] < 10^-13 &], #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] &][[1,1]]
xL3[list__] := Sort[Select[list, Abs[#[[2]]] < 10^-13 &], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &][[1,1]]
xL1[list__] := Select[list,Abs[#[[2]]] < 10^-13 && xL2[list] > #[[1]] > xL3[list] &][[1, 1]]

xL2[data]
xL3[data]
xL1[data]
```

> 0.969193
>
> -0.613042
>
> 0.302369

I think you get the idea.